# Apollo GraphQL + Minio - function callback never called

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, minio

I'm attempting to upload a file to Minio as part of an Apollo GraphQL mutation. For some reason, the callback in `minioClient.putObject()` is never called. I used this guide as my starting point: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/ and mixed it with Minio's example: https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference.html#putObject.

Here's my code:

```
    Mutation: {
        newFile: (parent, args) => {
            return args.file.then(file => {
                //Contents of Upload scalar: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload#class-graphqlupload
                //file.createReadStream() is a readable node stream that contains the contents of the uploaded file
                //node stream api: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html
                const stream = file.createReadStream();

                const fileName = file.filename;
                const mimetype = file.mimetype;
                const metaData = {
                    'Content-Type': mimetype,
                };
                // put it in the bucket
                minioClient.putObject(BUCKETNAME, fileName, stream, metaData, function (err, objInfo) {
                    console.log("shouldn't this run?");
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
                        console.log(objInfo);
                    }
                });
                return file;
            });
        },
```

GraphQL schema:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type File {
        filename: String!
        mimetype: String!
        encoding: String!
    }
    type Mutation {
        newFile(file: Upload!): File!
    }
```

I get no standard out from the code above. Only when I put console.log() above and below the `minioClient.putObject()` function.

There are no errors in the Chrome console or in NodeJS output.

I'm stumped as to why this callback isn't executed by the event loop.